# how do i use awk&sed to edit specific field by using matching input

Tags: shell, awk, sed

hi i am new to using awk and i am trying to edit a specific field based on input

e.g delimiter is :

```
 item.txt file
 comics:stan lee:5:1:2
 comics:stan lim:1:2:3
```

i want to use awk to display the entire line & i want to use sed to edit the 3rd field based on the input of user, how should i proceed from here?

```
 echo: "Enter Field 1: "
 read field_one
 echo: "Enter field 2: "
 read field_two
 #need awk statement
 echo "Enter New Field 3: "
 read field_three_new
 sed -i "/^$field_one:$field_two:/ s/$field_three_new/$field_three/" item.txt || tee item.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use sed to edit the line; it will end badly if the user enters something that sed interprets as a control character (such as `/`, `{`, `}`, `\` and so on). Try your script and enter `/` for one of the variables, sed will complain about syntax errors.

You can do both with awk:

```
echo "Enter Field 1: "
read field_one
echo "Enter field 2: "
read field_two

awk -F : -v f1="$field_one" -v f2="$field_two" '$1 == f1 && $2 == f2' item.txt

echo "Enter New Field 3: "
read field_three_new

# If you have GNU awk 4.1.0 or later:
awk -i inplace -F : -v f1="$field_one" -v f2="$field_two" -v f3="$field_three_new" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == f1 && $2 == f2 { $3 = f3 } 1' item.txt

# otherwise:
# the && between the commands are to short-circuit in case of an error; if one of
# the commands fails, the others should not be executed anymore. Kudos to
# Ed Morton for catching that.
tempfile=$(mktemp) &&
awk -F : -v f1="$field_one" -v f2="$field_two" -v f3="$field_three_new" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == f1 && $2 == f2 { $3 = f3 } 1' item.txt > "$tempfile" &&
mv "$tempfile" item.txt

# or, keeping a backup (this is my preferred method)
cp item.txt item.txt~ &&
awk -F : -v f1="$field_one" -v f2="$field_two" -v f3="$field_three_new" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == f1 && $2 == f2 { $3 = f3 } 1' item.txt~ > item.txt
```

The advantage is that the awk variables are set to the shell variables in a context in which no code interpretation takes place, so special characters are handled gracefully.

The awk code is fairly straightforward. The command line option `-F :` sets the field separator to `:`, so `$1` will be the first colon-delimited field (e.g. `comics`), `$2` the second (e.g. `stan lee`) and so forth. `-v varname=value` sets an awk variable named `varname` to the value `value`; the variable can later be used in the script.

In the first call, then,

```
$1 == f1 && $2 == f2
```

selects those lines in which field 1 is equal to `f1` (which is set to the first user input in the shell script), and field 2 is set to `f2` (which is set to the second).

In the second call,

```
BEGIN {                # once right at the start (before the first line)
  OFS = FS             # set the output field separator to the field separator.
}                      # Now both are :
$1 == f1 && $2 == f2 { # if the current line matches the condition from before
  $3 = f3              # replace the third field with the third user input
}
1                      # then select all lines for printing. This works because
                       # by convention, 1 means true (as do all non-zero values)
```

The `OFS = FS` thing is necessary because the default print action will print the fields one by one if a field is changed and place the output field separator between them. It does not matter for the unchanged lines, which are repeated verbatim.

Comment: hi i got a error saying not an option : -i when running this

Comment: The `-i inplace` requires GNU awk 4.1.0 or later. If you don't have that, redirect the output from awk to a temporary file and move that back to the original name afterwards.

Comment: so it should be awk > temp.txt?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I edited in how I would do it. Oh, and I would probably keep a backup of the original item.txt, just in case of an untimely disk error. I suppose then you could do `cp item.txt item.txt~; awk all that stuff item.txt~ > item.txt`.

Comment: i see is it possible for u to write it out cause i can't seem to visualize it

Comment: Edited it in. Seriously though, at this point my advice is that you read a shell tutorial from the beginning. It seems like you lack the understandng of very basic mechanisms, and stack-overflow driven development is not a sane model.

Comment: Never do `cmd file > tmp; mv tmp file`, always do `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` so that if `cmd` fails you haven't just wiped out your original file. e.g. imagine what would happen to `item.txt` in your final example if `cp item.txt item.txt~` failed. BTW you should be setting IFS= and using -r with read.

Comment: @Wintermute thx for the advise , i will go read more shell tutorials any suggestion on a good resource to use?